# QoS on pfSense 2

Tags: qos

I have a question about quality of service (QoS) on pfSense 2

I'm using pfSense 2 to load balance 2 internet line. I want to setup some rules let it work better for VoIP (Skype, x-lite), citrix, VPN, also limit download for users (torrent, video,...). I mean all thist services always get a good bandwidth than other.

Any ideas how to set this up?

Thanks!
PS: English is my foreign language :D

Answer (score 2):

Read the doc at the link below and then run the Traffic Shaping Wizard to see if that helps out.  If it doesn't then you can always go with limiters or L7 filtering (discussed in the same link but further down on the page).

http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Traffic_Shaping_Guide#PFSense_2.0_Traffic_Shaping_Guide_.28Work_In_progress.29

Comment: Hi Jason,
Many thanks for your guide, i'm on this way.